# Insert keywords (double quotes) in mongodb using insert statement. (Escape sequence)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to insert a string that contains double quotes and single quotes as below.

`db.collectionName.insert({"filedName" : "my field contains "double quotes"  and 'single quotes' how to insert"}) ;`

When I try insert above, it got error as my field contain double quotes, can some one tell me something like escape sequence to insert double quote?

Can't do as under my field also contain single quotes.
`db.collectionName.insert({"filedName" : 'my field contains "double quotes"  and 'single quotes' how to insert'}) ;`

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends on which context you use your code.
If it's in pure js (node.js for example) you can escape the quote char with `\`, like this :

```
db.collectionName.insert({"filedName" : "my field contains \"double quotes\" and 'single quotes' how to insert"}) ;
```

But in the HTML context it's not possible, you need to replace the double-quote with the proper XML entity representation, `&quot;`

Comment: Thanks BaptisteL

I want to insert from Mongo command line not from any application tool.

Comment: using 'MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4'
\ didn't worked with me to scape double quote.

Comment: it works for me with a 2.4.9 version. Sorry that it couldn't help. But I don't think it's a new feature. Maybe the problem is somewhere else. What's the error message by the way ?

Comment: didn't got any error it work as below:
db.collectionName.insert({"filedName" : "my field contains \"double quotes\" and 'single quotes' how to insert"}) ;
.....
.....
>
and no record inserted

Answer (score 0):

Consider using grave/accent (`` ` ``, [decimal ASCII code 96](https://www.ascii-code.com/)) for string enclosing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

JSON allows unicode syntax using \u1234 format according to ECMA-404. Therefore you can use the following syntax to insert double quote and single quotes from MongoDB shell.

```
db.collectionName.insert({"filedName" : "my field contains \u0022double quotes\u0022 and \u0027single quotes\u0027 how to insert"})
```

Further, you can use this syntax to insert non-ASCII characters too. This special handling is required if we are forming the JSON manually. If the JSON is being serialized automatically from plain objects (e.g. POJOs) using a framework such as GSON, Xstream the required conversion would happen automatically while converting to JSON.